# How can I remotely read binary registry data using Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010

I am trying to remotely read a binary (REG_BINARY) registry value, but I get nothing but junk back. Any ideas what is wrong with this code? I'm using Delphi 2010:

```
function GetBinaryRegistryData(ARootKey: HKEY; AKey, AValue, sMachine: string; var sResult: string): boolean;
    var
      MyReg: TRegistry;
      RegDataType: TRegDataType;
      DataSize, Len: integer;
      sBinData: string;
      bResult: Boolean;
    begin
      bResult := False;
      MyReg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_QUERY_VALUE);

      try
        MyReg.RootKey := ARootKey;
        if MyReg.RegistryConnect('\\' + sMachine) then
        begin
          if MyReg.KeyExists(AKey) then
          begin
            if MyReg.OpenKeyReadOnly(AKey) then
            begin
              try
                RegDataType := MyReg.GetDataType(AValue);
                if RegDataType = rdBinary then
                begin
                  DataSize := MyReg.GetDataSize(AValue);
                  if DataSize > 0 then
                  begin
                    SetLength(sBinData, DataSize);
                    Len := MyReg.ReadBinaryData(AValue, PChar(sBinData)^, DataSize);
                    if Len <> DataSize then
                      raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(ERROR_CANTREAD))
                    else
                    begin
                      sResult := sBinData;
                      bResult := True;
                    end;
                  end;
                end;
              except
                MyReg.CloseKey;
              end;
              MyReg.CloseKey;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        MyReg.Free;
      end;

      Result := bResult;
    end;
```

And I call it like this:

```
GetBinaryRegistryData(
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
   '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion', 
   'DigitalProductId', '192.168.100.105', 
   sProductId
);

WriteLn(sProductId);
```

The result I receive from the WriteLn on the console is:

```
ñ ♥ ???????????6Z ????1   ???????☺  ???♦            ??3   ? ??? ?
??
```

Comment: So all of the API calls indicate that they succeed, but you get incorrect data back?

Comment: Correct, I'll post what I get back.

Comment: If an exception occurs, you close the registry key twice, and your program continues running as though nothing is wrong. You don't need *either* of those `CloseKey` calls since the key will get closed when the object gets freed anyway. Don't catch an exception unless you know how to fix the problem that triggered it. (If you catch `EPrinterOnFire`, you'd better have a working `ExtinguishPrinter` function.)

Comment: And what did you expect to get on the console instead?

Comment: Ah, good catch, thank you Rob. That function is a mess and I will re-write it to be cleaner. It was a snippet I threw together from a much larger (and messier) function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are already connected remotely, try using the [`GetDataAsString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.GetDataAsString) function
to read binary data from the registry.

```
sResult := MyReg.GetDataAsString(AValue);
```

Comment: That will return a hex-formatted string.  If the user needs the actual binary data, he/she would have to decode the string back to its original binary.

Answer (score 5):

You're using Delphi 2010, so all your characters are two bytes wide. When you set the length of your result string, you're allocating *twice* the amount of space you need. Then you call `ReadBinaryData`, and it fills *half* your buffer. There are two bytes of data in each character. Look at each byte separately, and you'll probably find that your data looks less garbage-like.

Don't use strings for storing arbitrary data. Use strings for storing text. To store arbitrary blobs of data, use `TBytes`, which is an array of bytes.